# How to check if a table column exists using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, jdbc, jooq

I'm trying to write a query to check if a column exists within this table. As far as I can see, I can only query rows of columns. I'm wondering if there is a way to query if a column within a table exists?

```
String currentTable = "";
final Query query = dslContext
        .select(field(COLUMN_COUNTRY_CODE))
        .from(MANAGEMENT_TABLE_NAME)
        .orderBy(field(COLUMN_CREATE_DATE).desc())
        .limit(inline(1));
currentTable = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query.getSQL(), String.class);
```

This is what my query looks like at the moment. I want to check if `COLUMN_COUNTRY_CODE` column table exists in `MANAGEMENT_TABLE_NAME`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You would need to query the database metadata, not the table itself.

Comment: For the record, there's also `DSLContext.meta()` to query JDBC's `DatabaseMetaData`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JDBC, you can achieve this by creating an instance of [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) like so:

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
```

Where your `Connection` object is an instance of `JdbcConnection`.

Next, by using the `getColumns()` method you can iterate over the columns of a particular table and check their names.

Code sample:

```
    ResultSet columns = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null,null, "TABLE_NAME", null);
while(columns.next()) {
    String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME");    
}
```

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-database-metadata)